# How can I make Pandas read SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I have trouble making Pandas read SQL database.

The code below

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import connect
connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
#Create the database in RAM

cursor = connection.cursor()

sql_file = open(r'https://github.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook/raw/master/data/weather_2012.sqlite')
con = sqlite3.connect("data/weather_2012.sqlite")
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from weather_2012 LIMIT 3", con)
df
```

throws an error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-597-87fd38b9bc7a> in <module>
      6 cursor = connection.cursor()
      7 
----> 8 sql_file = open(r'https://github.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook/raw/master/data/weather_2012.sqlite')
      9 con = sqlite3.connect("data/weather_2012.sqlite")
     10 df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from weather_2012 LIMIT 3", con)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://github.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook/raw/master/data/weather_2012.sqlite'
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems to have always behaved this way.
Broadly speaking, how can I work with SQL from Python more conveniently?

Comment: If you have already fetched the file (to `data/weather_2012.sqlite`), then why do you have line 8 in there at all?  You can't `open` a URL as if it were a file.  You could use `requests` to fetch it, but if you already have the file, then that line shouldn't be in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Pavel Tashkinov,

As far as I'm aware, sqlite3 was only designed to deal with local files. To utilise the database, you might need to download it from the server. And you need the path to the file, not the URL.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('path/Downloads/weather_2012.sqlite')
con_memory = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from weather_2012 LIMIT 3", con)
print(df)

id            date_time  temp
1  2012-01-01 00:00:00  -1.8
2  2012-01-01 01:00:00  -1.8
3  2012-01-01 02:00:00  -1.8
```